# QuickTime Framework for connect Quicktime Player in mac

Tags: macos, quicktime

I need to develop app in MAC to Connect Running Quicktime Player and control it(Such as Play, Stop, Audio adjustment,Open,Recording,etc..)

Is there any Open Source Framework or Library to connect Quicktime Player in Mac?

Answer (score 1):

You can use AppleScript for this. There isn't another way.